# Jquery Plugin - This id is undefined

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

i try to write my first jquery plugin.

**JS Code**

```
$('#test').existInTip();

(function($){
$.fn.existInTip = function(){
   console.log($(this).attr('id'));
}
})(jQuery);
```

But i get an undefined error? Whats wrong?

**Thanks in advance!**
Peter

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to use `existInTip` before the plugin is declared. Switch the order:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.existInTip = function(){
        console.log($(this).attr('id'));
    }
})(jQuery);

$('#test').existInTip();
```

If this code is in the `<head>` section of your page, you also want to put the last line inside a `document ready` handler:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#test').existInTip();
});
```

One more thing: Inside a jQuery plugin, `this` is already the jQuery object, so there's no need to wrap it:

```
$.fn.existInTip = function(){
    console.log(this.attr('id')); // Or this[0].id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should make sure the script is declared and parsed before using it. Try swapping the two code blocks around.

Answer (score 0):

`$(this)` may be used with an instanced object.

`$.fn.existInTip` is a function.